# What is the reason that a subquery is returning data for first record only?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this query

```
SELECT ORIG.FORM_SUBMISSION_NUMBER,
    ORIG.DATE_SUBMITTED,
    (SELECT MAX(SUB.DATE_SUBMITTED)
        FROM myView SUB
        WHERE SUB.BASEMENT_GENERAL_OK_CHKB = 1
        AND SUB.DATE_SUBMITTED < ORIG.DATE_SUBMITTED 
    ) AS BASEMENT_GENERAL_OK
FROM  myView ORIG 
WHERE ORIG.DATE_SUBMITTED >= '03-APR-17'
AND ORIG.DATE_SUBMITTED <= '10-APR-17'
ORDER BY ORIG.DATE_SUBMITTED
```

Here is the result of the query

[image: This is the result of the query]

the last column should have data for every record, I checked that myself form the view. I also rewrote the query to use left join on the same view and it works perfectly fine. I am in a situation where I can't do it through join and I was wondering why this isn't working while it should.

**Note: Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.0**

As far as I know this query was working before upgrading to this version or oracle

I tried this 
`ALTER SESSION SET optimizer_features_enable='11.2.0.1';` with no luck

Comment: May be not related, but don't use `date` as string.  Rather use `to_date('03-APR-17','DD-MON-RR')` and `to_date('10-APR-17','DD-MON-RR')`

Comment: Maybe add the relevant data from the view, though it seems fairly obvious that all of the rows should show either that same time on the 2nd, or a later value. Maybe the view is doing something odd that is getting confused; can you include the code for that in the question? (Also please post text, [not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: how you show the result? .. check if you ide not suppress same values in columns?  .. eg sqlplus to this in some column setting

Comment: Maybe not related, but shouldn't your subquery have a `SUB.FORM_SUBMISSION_NUMBER = ORIG.FORM_SUBMISSION_NUMBER` ?

Comment: @Utsav, or even better use `to_date('10-04-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')`, resp `to_date('10-APR-2017','DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')`

Comment: It works for me on 11XE and on 12.2 via livesql.oracle.com.  However, I made some assumptions about sample data, so I can't be too sure.  If you want continued help on this, provide sample data and do not post images (as mentioned above).